# c# dropdownlist avoid multiple insert statements?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

This is c# code:

```
DropDownList ddl;
ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Me--", "0"));
ddl.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("I'm the first", "1"));
ddl.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("I'm the second", "2"));
ddl.Items.Insert(3, new ListItem("I'm the third", "3"));
```

Is there a way we can avoid these sequential insert into dropdownlist and bulk insert these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.addrange(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
DropDownList ddl;
ddl.Items.AddRange(new ListItem[] { new ListItem ("--Select Me--", "0"), new ListItem("I'm the first", "1"), new ListItem("I'm the second", "2"), new ListItem("I'm the third", "3")});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
DropDownList ddl;
var ls=new List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<int,string>(0,"--Select Me--"),
    new KeyValuePair<int,string>(1,"I'm the first"),
    new KeyValuePair<int,string>(2,"I'm the second"),
    new KeyValuePair<int,string>(3,"I'm the third"),
};
ddl.DataTextField="Value";
ddl.DataValueField="Key";
ddl.DataSource=ls;
ddl.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful:

```
List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
  items.Add(new ListItem("Alabama", "Alabama"));
  items.Add(new ListItem("Alaska", "Alaska"));
  DropDownList1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.Items.AddRange(new[]
{
    new ListItem("--Select Me--", "0"),
    new ListItem("I'm the first", "1"),
    new ListItem("I'm the second", "2"),
    new ListItem("I'm the third", "3")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select Me--", "0"));
ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("I'm the first", "1"));
ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("I'm the second", "2"));
ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("I'm the third", "3"));
```